# PTIJ: Who is Sinai?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It says in the very famous [first mishna of Avot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "...משֶׁה קִבֵּל תּוֹרָה מִסִּינַי, וּמְסָרָהּ לִיהוֹשֻׁעַ"

Translation: Moshe received the Torah from Sinai and gave it to Yehoshua, etc.

Now, this shocked me. I was always taught that Moshe received the Torah from Hashem and that Sinai is a mountain. Apparently though, Sinai was the first person to get the Torah. Who's this Sinai person and where'd he get the Torah from?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's a gemara mefurash ([*Horayos* 14a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=28&daf=14&format=text))  "רב יוסף סיני".

Comment: @Fred Rav Yosef was before Moshe?

Comment: Why can't Sinai be an object? Why does it have to be a person? For example, the sky "gives" us rain and snow. Likewise, Sinai can be a mountain and the mountain is giving us something.

Comment: Indeed. Abaye and Rava lived at the same time as משה בר עצרי ([*'Arachin* 23a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=23&format=text)), which was one generation after Rav Yosef.

Comment: @DanF do mountains usually give Torahs? I was not aware... I guess I don't climb enough mountains...

Comment: @fred in my haste to answer, I hadn't looked in the comments... Baruch Shekivanti

Comment: " do mountains usually give Torahs?" Of course they do! Haven't you seen the movie "The Ten Commandments"? A huge ball of fire goes into the side of the mountain and bam! Two stone tablets emerge.

Comment: @DanF actually no, I've never seen the movie. Yeah, חור בהשכלה...is fire a necessity to draw out Torahs from mountains or can it be done some other way?

Comment: The story goes that the satmar rebbe was giving a test and a boy called moshe ben sinai (yes his real name) answered incorrectly. So the rebbe said to him 'moshe' did you by chance  mekabel this also from sinai.

Answer (score 4):

It's a clear Gemara ([Berachot 64a](http://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Berakhot/64a.1#e0n6), [Horayot 14a](http://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Horayot/14a.1#e0n6)):

> דְּרַב יוֹסֵף סִינַי
>
> Rav Yosef was Sinai.

Thus, Moshe was taught by Rav Yosef!

Answer (score 2):

Sini must be from the sons of Aaron, as well as Tabor and Carmel. We can see this from the Gemara in Megila 29a:

> דרש בר קפרא מאי דכתיב (תהלים סח, יז) למה תרצדון הרים גבנונים יצתה בת קול ואמרה להם למה תרצו דין עם סיני כולכם בעלי מומים אתם אצל סיני כתיב הכא גבנונים וכתיב התם (ויקרא כא, כ) או גבן או דק אמר רב אשי ש"מ האי מאן דיהיר בעל מום הוא
>
> Bar Kappara interpreted a verse homiletically: What is the meaning of that which is written: “Why do you look askance [teratzdun], O high-peaked mountains, at the mountain that God has desired for His abode” (Psalms 68:17)? A Divine Voice issued forth and said: Why do you seek [tirtzu] to enter into a legal dispute [din] with Sinai? You are all blemished in comparison to Sinai, as it is written here: “gavnunnim” and it is written there, with regard to the blemishes that disqualify a priest: “Or crookbacked [gibben] or a dwarf” (Leviticus 21:20). Rav Ashi said: Learn from this that one who is arrogant is considered blemished.

Since the blemish of gibben is only a blemish by kohanim, as stated in the Mishnah in Bechoros, it must be that Sini is a cohen.

Comment: Okay, next question: why are these people compared to mountains? And from where did Sinai get the Torah to give Moshe?

Answer (score 2):

Abraham fulfilled the whole Torah (see Yoma 28b).

One is required to teach their children Torah, see Deuteronomy 6.

Abraham did this and then sent his children to the east (Genesis 25).

The Torah is thus from [סיני](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9F_(%D7%90%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8)) - not a person but a people, the Chinese, the descendants of Abraham who dwell in the east.

Comment: Shouldn't it then be מהסיני or מסינים?

Comment: לעולם ישנה אדם לתלמידו דרך קצרה